# save RadixTree as file

Tags: java, tree

I use ConcurrentRadixTree and put > 1 million words into it.
The creation of this tree takes much time, so I thought about creating my tree only once and save it as a file -> so I can load my tree from file for next use instead of create it again (which should be much faster).

```
File file = new File(myPath);
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
s.writeObject(myTree);
s.close();
```

But when I try to store, I get "NotSerializableException":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: com.googlecode.concurrenttrees.radix.ConcurrentRadixTree
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at ForTests.main(Test.java:29)
```

Any idea how to store a RadixTree?

Answer (score 0):

Reason you are getting your exception is that the object you are using is not serializable

Easiest solution I can think of is to extend your tree implementation :

```
public class YourSerializableClass extends ConcurrentRadixTree implements Serializable
```

Alternatively you can implement your own `readObject writeObject` methods. More information here :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html